# w32time: The computer did not resync because no time data was available

Tags: networking, sync, time, windows-services, ntp

I am using `Windows Time Service` to synchronize the time between two machines in a network. The network is isolated and it doesn't have internet connectivity. I configure one of the machines in the network as the server and the other as the client.

The Server configuration `w32tm /query /configuration` is as follows. The `NTPServer bit` is enabled in the machine.

```
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 30000 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Local)
Type: NT5DS (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
```

The client configuration is as follows.

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 1 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 360000 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 604800 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: [172.19.36.138],0x8 (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

You can see `NtpServer: [172.19.36.138],0x8 (Local)` above which is pointing to the Server that I have configured. I am able to ping between the two machines.

If I try to run `w32tm /resync` from client it says

```
Sending resync command to local computer
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

Why is this happening and How can I fix it.?

Answer (score 11):

1. Reboot the time service

   ```
   net stop w32time
   net start w32time
   ```
2. Tell the time sync service to use the changes

   ```
   w32tm /config /update
   ```
3. Reset the local computer's time against the time server

   ```
   w32tm /resync /rediscover
   ```

The last command will force redetection of network resourced.
Note: Resync succeeds even though the error message below appears.

```
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

p.s. Please also check whether your firewall allows the ports needed by the time service.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is the installation of the pool.ntp.org.

The installation of the pool.ntp.org time server is recommended by the manual by the following command :

```
w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org,0x8 1.pool.ntp.org,0x8 2.pool.ntp.org,0x8 3.pool.ntp.org,0x8" /syncfromflags:MANUAL
```

The additional information you can find here:
https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/WindowsTimeService

Comment: looks like all time servers were deleted by some MS update for Win10. This did the trick (not if MS would just put something this rudimentary into the Control Panel, that would be great!).

Answer (score 0):

FYI please notice on your server:

```
VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
```

This means it is a VM getting its time from it's host, NOT the domain on `NT5DS` like you may think it is.

Also on your client check if those brackets `[ ]` are correct, I'm using a DNS name and seen no brackets, not sure but that may not be the correct syntax.