# Windows Time - The computer did not resync because no time data was available

Tags: windows, time

I was following the instructions in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626035/2227908) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862236/how-to-sync-windows-time-from-a-ntp-time-server-in-command) when the following popped up when I tried to sync Windows Time to `pool.ntp.org`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /resync
Sending resync command to local computer
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

The following is the configuration:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 5 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 1 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 360000 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 32768 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: pool.ntp.org (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

I've tried un- and re-registering the Windows Time service, but do no avail.

How do I solve this problem?

Edit: the output of `w32tm /monitor /computers:pool.ntp.org`:

```
pool.ntp.org[27.124.125.250:123]:
    ICMP: 80ms delay
    NTP: +1.4521260s offset from local clock
        RefID: ntp.waia.asn.au [218.100.43.70]
        Stratum: 2

Warning:
Reverse name resolution is best effort. It may not be
correct since RefID field in time packets differs across
NTP implementations and may not be using IP addresses.
```

Screenshot of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\w32time\Parameters`:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this link, it could be helpful. 
 https://superuser.com/questions/1116938/w32time-the-computer-did-not-resync-because-no-time-data-was-available

Comment: What's the output of `w32tm /monitor /computers:pool.ntp.org`?

Comment: @OOOO Yes I have. The error message popped up, as stated by the answer, but it evidently did not sync as my computer is still 1.5s behind the authoritative time server.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Sorry the code looks horrible in the comments, I have edited my post to include the output.

Comment: Could you also include a screenshot of ` HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters`?

Comment: @harrymc Edited post to include it

Comment: The [manual](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/WindowsTimeService) says that you should configure this service using in an elevated cmd the command : `w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org,0x8 1.pool.ntp.org,0x8 2.pool.ntp.org,0x8 3.pool.ntp.org,0x8" /syncfromflags:MANUAL`. This should not be used for a member of a domain.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you, it worked perfectly! I'm not sure why this didn't work when I tried it before, maybe a simply restart also helped.

Comment: I added an answer below. Accepting it would be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installation of the `pool.ntp.org` time server is recommended by the
[manual](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/WindowsTimeService)
by the following command :

```
w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org,0x8 1.pool.ntp.org,0x8 2.pool.ntp.org,0x8 3.pool.ntp.org,0x8" /syncfromflags:MANUAL
```